# SQL Query in Python - Insert value from Python in SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, timestamp

I have a SQL query in python that is filtered on Timestamp, however the Timestamp changes based on a value from a dataframe.

```
query = """(SELECT [ID],[Timestamp],[Value] FROM [table] Where [Timestamp] >= '2021-10-13') alias"""

big_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", driver).option("url", url).option("dbtable", query).load()
```

How can I replace '2021-10-13' below to the inserted value from the python dataframe where the value will change? For example it will be 2021-01-01 in this dataframe.

```
print(somedf.Timestamp.min())
'2021-01-01'

query = """(SELECT [ID],[Timestamp],[Value] FROM [table] Where [Timestamp] >= somedf.Timestamp.min()) alias"""
```

Obviously the top line will not work

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a great use for string formatting:

```py
query = f"(SELECT [ID],[Timestamp],[Value] FROM [table] Where [Timestamp] >= {somedf.Timestamp.min()} alias)"
```

Don't forget the lowercase `f` at the beginning of the string, that indicates that its formatted. Lemme know if this doesn't work for you.

David

Comment: I tried this, however an error is thrown at line 2 in the first snippet: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parse error at line: 1, column: 102: Incorrect syntax near &#39;alias&#39;.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert some string like this

```
query = """(SELECT [ID],[Timestamp],[Value] FROM [table] Where [Timestamp] >= %s) alias""" % somedf.Timestamp.min().strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

Comment: I tried this, however an error was thrown on line 2 in the first code snippet: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parse error at line: 1, column: 101: Expected but did not find a closing quotation mark after the character string &#39;) alias WHERE 1=0.